# Variable is not storing the right string

Tags: batch-file

I have created this batch script to remove the blackout.

```
C:\oem\agent_inst\bin\emctl status blackout > c:\temp\bo_status.txt | for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr Blackoutname c:\temp\bo_status.txt') do SET bo=%%a
C:\oem\agent_inst\bin\emctl stop blackout %bo%
del c:\temp\bo_status.txt
```

and my `c:\temp\bo_status.txt` file content is as below:

> Blackoutname = abc_12__america Targets = (america.host.com,) Time =
>   ({2019-01-23|12:27:47|720 Min,|} ) Expired = False

but when I run the batch script its not taking this blackout name (`abc_12__america`) instead its keep taking `abc_1__america` name in `%bo%` variable. I am not sure how this name is stuck in the buffer.

Below is the output when I run the batch script

```
c:\>bo_stop.bat

c:\>C:\oem\agent_inst\bin\emctl status blackout   1>c:\temp\bo_status.txt  | for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('findstr Blackoutname c:\temp\bo_status.txt') do SET bo=%a

c:\>C:\oem\agent_inst\bin\emctl stop blackout  abc_1__america
Blackout stop Error : Blackout "abc_1__america" does not exist
```

kindly help me on this please.

Comment: I would like to know how the variable `bo` is getting assigned `abc_1__america`.  It is not in your text file example.

Comment: What is the reason to use `|` in the first line since you're redirecting all output of the command to a file?

Comment: @Squashman if I don't use | batch script is not moving ahed. Its just redirect the output into c:\temp\bo_status.txt and stop the execution.
and even I am wondering how *bo* is getting assinged with abc_1__america though its not in .txt file. But one thing I would like to let you know abc_1__america was assigned earlier when .txt has the same. But not its changed with abc_12__america

Comment: `for /F "tokens=2 delims=="` --> `for /F "tokens=2 delims== "`. Anyway, I'd not use a temporary text file but parse the output of `emctl status blackout` directly: `for /F "tokens=2 delims== " %%a in ('emctl status blackout') do set "bo=%%a"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piping does not make any sense here. On the right side of the pipe, the file is not yet created, resulting in "nothing found", so the variable `bo` just keeps its previous content. Don't use pipe:

```
call "C:\oem\agent_inst\bin\emctl" status blackout > c:\temp\bo_status.txt
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr Blackoutname c:\temp\bo_status.txt') do SET bo=%%a
call "C:\oem\agent_inst\bin\emctl" stop blackout %bo%
del c:\temp\bo_status.txt
```

The reason, why your script refused to continue is `emctl` being a batch file. Just executing it with it's name means to transfer control to it (it will never return control to your original script). To be able to return, you need to `call` it. (modified code above to reflect this to help future readers)

Comment: Thanks, but if I don't use pipe script is not moving ahead even. Please check the below output.

Comment: **c:\>bo_stop.bat**

c:\>C:\oem\agent_inst\bin\emctl status blackout  1>c:\temp\bo_status.txt

c:\>

Comment: if `emctl` is a batch file `.cmd` or `.bat`, you need to `call` it: `call "C:\oem\agent_inst\bin\emctl" status blackout > c:\temp\bo_status.txt`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware about the **call** here. It working now.